# Can I set a rule in the layer style that specifies the BBOX I need?

Tags: geoserver

The server is very slow to produce an image when the client requests an image at a scale of 900 layers but only one layer has the requested bbox. I think that GeoServer loads information about all the layers that fall under the scale rule in the style, and then starts filtering them by BBOX. I think that if you set a bounding box in the style rule, and I think that then the GeoServer will not load information about all layers that do not fall into the BBOX of the request from the client.

> I tried to use cql filter, but I can't change the request from the
>   client and add &CQL_FILTER=test to it&

```
http://192.168.0.163:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?STYLES=&VERSION=1.3.0&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&LAYERS=cite%3AALLGroup&EXCEPTIONS=INIMAGE&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&CRS=EPSG%3A900913&BBOX=6770791.9617694,7697820.240683,6771097.7098825,7698125.9887961&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256
```

I'm trying to set a bounding box in style. Can I set a rule in the layer style that specifies the BBOX I need?

> Each layer is a pyramid of images created using gdal from tiff. 100
>   000 * 100 000 pixels.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
 xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">

  <!-- a Named Layer is the basic building block of an SLD document -->
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>default_raster</Name>
    <UserStyle>
    <!-- Styles can have names, titles and abstracts -->
      <Title>Default Raster</Title>
      <Abstract>A sample style that draws a raster, good for displaying imagery</Abstract>
      <!-- FeatureTypeStyles describe how to render different features -->
      <!-- A FeatureTypeStyle for rendering rasters -->
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
            <MinScaleDenominator>00001</MinScaleDenominator>
            <MaxScaleDenominator>10000</MaxScaleDenominator>
            <RasterSymbolizer>
                <Opacity>1.0</Opacity>
            </RasterSymbolizer>
        </Rule> 

        <gml:BBOX>
        <PropertyName>GEOMETRY</PropertyName>
        <gml:Box srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326">
          <gml:coord>
             <gml:X>-10</gml:X> <gml:Y>0</gml:Y>
          </gml:coord>
          <gml:coord>
             <gml:X>10</gml:X> <gml:Y>10</gml:Y>
          </gml:coord>
        </gml:Box>
      </gml:BBOX>

      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

getting an error:

> line 28: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting
>   with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2":BBOX}'. One of
>   '{"http://www.opengis.net/sld":Rule,
>   "http://www.opengis.net/sld":VendorOption}' is expected.

Comment: I don't know your use case but perhaps you could combine your 900 raster layers into one layer with raster mosaic.

Comment: This is really an extension of  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349668/how-do-i-avoid-wasting-time-on-operations-before-doesnt-intersect-the-coverage but you haven't answered my questions there. Filters in the styles are unlikely to help you

Comment: If you have 900 raster layers the best approach is to use a single image mosaic instead, it keeps an index of where each image is, and will quickly determine the only ones intersecting the requested BBOX.

Comment: @user30184 Each layer is a pyramid of images created using gdal from tiff. 100 000 * 100 000 pixels. I won't be able to combine that many people into a single pyramid.

Comment: @IanTurton  The problem is really one and I try to ask small questions to understand how to solve this problem. I provided logs from Geoserver, but I may have incorrectly notified you in the comment because I didn't get a response. When applying the scale rule, the server does not read data from all layers, and I think a bbox-style filter will help you not process unnecessary data. Why does GeoServer load the data of all pyramids that do not fall under the BBOX request from the client and how to prevent this?

Comment: Depends on how you set it up which is the missing information I asked for

Comment: Image mosaic does not mean that you must combine images into a new pyramid. Image mosaic is an image index in vector format, same approach that GDAL is using with virtual rasters (VRT) (with gdalbuildvrt) or MapServer with raster tileindex (with gdaltindex). That said, it is relevant to ask why GeoServer does not skip faster the layers which are outside the bbox of the request.

Comment: @AndreaAime  Image size 10 000 000 * 3 000 000 pixels convert to mosaic with tile 10 000*10 000 and this should work faster?  Gdal slowly creates a pyramid as the size of the original image increases. I'll try to do that. Thanks!

Comment: GeoServer does not skip them because it has no logic to do so, the bbox configured in the layer very often cannot be trusted, either because the data changed in the back, or because it was entered incorrectly. The BBOX is just metadata for the capabilities documents, gives you an initial area where to look.

Comment: @4gexotron I only suggested to use the geoserver image mosaic plugin, I did not suggest to merge the images in advance via gdal.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter needs to be inside a `Filter` element which is inside a `Rule`- see the [SLD reference](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rules.html#syntax) on syntax.

```
<Rule>
   <Filter>
     <gml:BBOX>
        <PropertyName>GEOMETRY</PropertyName>
        <gml:Box srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326">
          <gml:coord>
             <gml:X>-10</gml:X> <gml:Y>0</gml:Y>
          </gml:coord>
          <gml:coord>
             <gml:X>10</gml:X> <gml:Y>10</gml:Y>
          </gml:coord>
        </gml:Box>
      </gml:BBOX>
      </Filter>
```

Comment: error  line 29: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/sld":Filter}'

Comment: if <ogc:Filter> then  line 30: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2":BBOX}'