# Performance of GeoServer for thousands of spatial data files

Tags: geoserver, gdal, geowebcache

**Input:**

thousands of large files (from 1mb to 5gb) containing the coordinates of the points (x, y, z) in a specific coordinate system. Points can intersects

It is required to make an online service where on top of the map there will be a colored surface (like a heatmap depending on the Z coordinate) with some interactive functions. More precisely 3 surfaces with different color maps and you can switch between them

Now GeoServer (with GeoWebCache), GDAL utilities, and some web-stack with leaflet+OSM at the front are used.

**How it works now:**

1. Preparing files using the GDAL utilities.

   - *'og2ogr'* to Shapefile from CSV (with srs changing)
   - *'gdal_grid -zfield Z'* from Shapefile to Tiff
   - 3 times *'gdaldem color-relief ... map.txt ... -alpha'* for coloring Tiff and *'gdal_translate -of PNG -scale -co worldfile = yes ...'* for creating PNG Worldfile.
     Output 3 PNG heatmaps in different colors.
2. Upload PNG to GeoServer. We have 3 groups of layers by color. Adding a new layer to a group of layers and recalculating the boundaries of the group.
3. On the front by *'L.tileLayer.wms'* we show the desired group of layers from GeoServer.
   [image: how it looks now]

**Problems and question:**

The main problem is the performance. For the quickness on the client, I run Seed in the GWC of each group, but it works very slowly. (for example, 1 group, 300 layers in a group, zoom up to 17 can go about a day). But after the cache is ready, everything works quickly on the client. But as boundaries grow, productivity gets worse.

This is my first GIS project and I do not have enough knowledge. It seems to me that my decision is not good and not optimal. What optimal approaches and tools can be used to solve such a problem, and what parameters/options can speed it up?

Comment: why not one tiff and three slds to do the mapping - make sure tiff is tiled and compressed with overviews

Comment: How to merge files into one tiff? gdal_merge freezes on so many files

Comment: you have a single tif as the output to step 2 - also mosaic the files rather than use a layergroup

Comment: probable duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349668/how-do-i-avoid-wasting-time-on-operations-before-doesnt-intersect-the-coverage/351120#351120

Comment: My question is more about the approach, not only about performance. Before creating a single tiff, I have other problems. For example, what is the best way to create a tiff with a surface, instead of a set of points using gdal from XYZ csv file.